# How can I detect when the line has crossed both sides of my curve?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

Is there a way of detecting when the line (drawn by the mouse) has interseted both sides of the curve? The aim of my game is for the user to successfully cut the object using the mouse.[image]

```
let level4;
window.onload = function() {
    let gameConfig = {
        transparent: true,
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        scale: {
            mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
            autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
            parent: "thegame",
            width: 600,
            height: 700
        },
        scene: scene4,
        physics: {
            default: "matter",
            matter: {
                gravity: {
                    y: 0
                },
                debug: true,
            }
        }
    }
    level4 = new Phaser.Game(gameConfig);
    window.focus();
}
let levelText;
class scene4 extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }


    create(){
        const graphics = this.add.graphics();

        const path = new Phaser.Curves.Path(0, 300);

        for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            // xRadius, yRadius, startAngle, endAngle, clockwise, rotation
            if (i % 2 === 0)
            {
                path.ellipseTo(50, 80, 180, 360, true, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                path.ellipseTo(50, 80, 180, 360, false, 0);
            }
        }

        graphics.lineStyle(40, 0xff0000, 1);

        path.draw(graphics);




        this.lineGraphics = this.add.graphics();
        this.input.on("pointerdown", this.startDrawing, this);
        this.input.on("pointerup", this.stopDrawing, this);
        this.input.on("pointermove", this.keepDrawing, this);
        this.isDrawing = false;
        levelText = this.add.text(13, 11, 'Level 4',{fontFamily: 'Georgia, "Goudy Bookletter 1911", Times, serif'});

    }
           
    startDrawing(){
        this.isDrawing = true;
    }
    keepDrawing(pointer){
        if(this.isDrawing){
            this.lineGraphics.clear();
            this.lineGraphics.lineStyle(5, 'black');
            this.lineGraphics.moveTo(pointer.downX, pointer.downY);
            this.lineGraphics.lineTo(pointer.x, pointer.y);
            this.lineGraphics.strokePath();
        }
    }

    updateLine(){
        //this.lineGraphics.clear();
        this.lineGraphics.lineStyle(15, 'black');
        this.lineGraphics.moveTo(linePoints[0].x, linePoints[0].y);
        for(var i = 1; i < linePoints.length; i++) {
            this.lineGraphics.lineTo(linePoints[i].x, linePoints[i].y);
        }
        this.lineGraphics.strokePath();
    }
    

    stopDrawing(pointer){
        if (????){
            this.isDrawing = false;
            levelText.setVisible(false);
            this.add.text(190, 300, 'Level 4 complete!',{fontFamily: 'Georgia, "Goudy Bookletter 1911", Times, serif', fontSize: '60px'}).bringToTop();
            }
        };
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

After the line has sucessfully cut the curve I would like "Level 4 complete to be printed".

Comment: Where are you calling `updateLine`? You can remove that function if I'm correct. So, you're having on pointerup a line made of two points: down.x,y and up.x,y - now you might want to check for line collision with an irregular shape, and both points not being in collision. Have you made any research? You might be interested in separating axis theorem or the point-in-polygon algorithm. What you're trying to accomplish is pretty complex. Not sure if Matter has some methods that can get you covered perfectly. Again, do a research on Query.region, SAT.collides, or Bounds.overlaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create *points* from the Phaser `Path` using the function `getPoints(...)` ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Curves.Path.html#getPoints__anchor)), and than try to intersect the drawn line with the points, with the function `GetLineToPoints(...)` ([link to documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Geom.Intersects.html#.GetLineToPoints__anchor)).
This should work well, depending on how exact you need this to work.

**Short Demo:**
*Adapted from your code.*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class Scene4 extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    create() {
        this.label = this.add.text(10,10, 'cut the line')
            .setScale(1.5)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
        this.lineGraphics = this.add.graphics()
            .setDepth(100);
    
        let graphics = this.add.graphics();
        this.path = new Phaser.Curves.Path(0, 90);

        for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            this.path.ellipseTo(35, 30, 180, 360, i % 2 === 0, 0);
        }

        graphics.lineStyle(30, 0xff0000, 1);

        this.path.draw(graphics);
        this.isDrawing = false;
    
        this.input.on("pointerdown", this.startDrawing, this);
        this.input.on("pointerup", this.stopDrawing, this);
        this.input.on("pointermove", this.keepDrawing, this);
    }
    
    startDrawing(){
        this.isDrawing = true;
        this.label.setText('cut the line');
    }
    
    keepDrawing(pointer){
        if(this.isDrawing){
            let vector = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(pointer.x - pointer.downX, pointer.y - pointer.downY);
            vector.limit(100); // --> Length limit
            this.lineGraphics.clear();
            this.lineGraphics.lineStyle(4, 0xffffff);
            this.lineGraphics.moveTo(pointer.downX, pointer.downY);
            this.lineGraphics.lineTo(pointer.downX + vector.x, pointer.downY + vector.y);           
            this.lineGraphics.stroke();
        }
    }
   
    stopDrawing(pointer){
        
        let vector = new Phaser.Math.Vector2(pointer.x - pointer.downX, pointer.y - pointer.downY);
        vector.limit(100); // --> Length limit
        
        // you can make more or less division depending on path complexity
        let points = this.path.getPoints(100);        
        let drawnLine = new Phaser.Geom.Line(pointer.downX, pointer.downY, pointer.downX + vector.x, pointer.downY + vector.y);
        let intersection = Phaser.Geom. Intersects.GetLineToPoints(
            drawnLine,
            points
        );
        
        // check if the cut-line has a mini length and if there is a intersection
        if (intersection && Phaser.Geom.Line.Length(drawnLine) > 45 ){
            this.label.setText('LINE CROSSED');
        }
        
        this.isDrawing = false;
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: [ Scene4 ]
}; 

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

> For more exact recognition, you would have to expand on this idea, but should be straightforward.

Comment: thank you very much, this worked exactly as I am wanting! thank you

Comment: Great to hear, if so could you consider accepting the answer with the green checkmark that would be great.

Comment: done! do you know if it's possible to set a maxium line length that the user can draw? The aim is for them to cut the shape, but if they draw a line covering the whole page they will easily pass, I am just trying to make it a bit harder. maybe set the maxium length you can draw slightly thicker than the shape?

Comment: Thanks. You could use `Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(...)` [Link to Documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Math.Distance.html) to restrict the length.

Comment: would I do this within the stopDrawing(pointer) function?

Comment: in the `keepDrawing` and the `stopDrawing` function.

Comment: okay thanks! I have changed the code to this: "        if (intersection && Phaser.Geom.Line.Length(drawnLine) < 100 ){
            this.levelText.setText('Level 1 complete!');  
        }" is this the most efficient way to achieve this? How do I enciorporate this into keepDrawing() so that the line can't be drawn any longer than 100?

Comment: I usually don't answer too many extra questions in the comment, because they are hard to follow, for other people and the code is hard to read. (I recommend, in general asking a new question). That said, I updated my answer to show how I would solve this with Phaser Vectors, it is abit more complicated, but it is probably the most efficient way to do this. [link to documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Math.Vector2.html)